# Склонение имен, фамилий - php класс

Tags: php

Всем привет! Хочу реализовать на сайте функцию склонения имен и фамилий, но в интернете ничего подобного не нашел, а именно не нашел класс php, который бы склонял имена. Единственное, что я нашел, это сервис яндекса, который склоняет имена и фамилии, но пользоваться я им не хочу, лучше всего бы использовать свой php класс, чем посторонние сервисы.

Может быть, кто знает где взять такой класс или уже есть у кого-нибудь или есть мысли, как его написать. За любую помощь буду рад.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как это вы не нашли? Есть же: [на яваскрипте](http://agalkin.ru/js/russian-name.php),  на пхп тоже есть: [склоняем фамилию на php](http://www.web-junior.net/sklonyaem-familiyu-na-php/).

Алгоритм у них похоже одинаковый.

Answer (score 2):

Хоть и через 5 лет, но решение теперь есть - https://github.com/wapmorgan/Morphos (http://morphos.io/)

Без словарей, без сторонних сервисов. Склоняет имена, города, слова, числа и вообще много чего умеет